# How to delete a map in Google mapsengine.google.com?

Tags: google-maps

I cannot find a delete button for my map on `mapsengine.google.com`.

I tried to look for it when opening a map and when editing an opened map but I cannot find it anywhere.

Is is possible to delete a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mapsengine.google.com, you can delete your unused maps.

1. Select the map to be deleted.
2. In the 'Key Box' with the Title and Description, there is a folder icon.
3. Click the folder for a drop down menu to appear.
4. Select the action 'Delete this map'

The map will no longer appear in your list of maps. It can not be retrieved.

[image]